# White spots (reflections?) appearing in Blender Internal Render

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I am rendering an animation in Blender Internal Render. The problem is, white areas/spots are apperaing on the floor of the scene (which is a textured plain). 
[image: Maybe it´s difficult to see, i´ve encirceled it]

[image]

Playing the rendered scene, I see them flicker everywhere. (You can already see them while the pictures are rendering) Do you think it is related to the lamps? There are two lamps, one Point-light behind the Camera and a Hemi in the sky behind the rocks in the back. Increasing the light-intensity of both lamps helps a bit, but I don´t want the scene to be too bright. I´ve already tried to darken the Material of the plane, but it doesn´t help.

I´ve found anything about this in the internet, problems with white spots are mostly referring to fireflies in Cycles, but I am using Blender Internal.

Do you know any solution?

Greetings!
MM

Comment: Maybe flickering of duplicated geometry? In edit mode Mesh/Vertices/Remove Doubles may help...

Comment: Finally I´ve solved the problem by turning down the alpha transparency for the specular areas in the Marterial panel. I´ve found the solution by trying out different things, but I don´t know WHY it worked or what it means...